# Transforming between ETRS89, WGS84, and Gauß-Krüger correctly using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have some projects where I work with this coordinate system:

> DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4
>   WKID: 31468 Authority: EPSG
>   Projection: Gauss_Kruger
>   False_Easting: 4500000.0
>   False_Northing: 0.0
>   Central_Meridian: 12.0
>   Scale_Factor: 1.0
>   Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.0
>   Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

I usually get my data in ETRS89:

> ETRS_1989_ETRS-TM32
>   WKID: 3044 Authority: EPSG
>   Projection: Transverse_Mercator
>   False_Easting: 500000.0
>   False_Northing: 0.0
>   Central_Meridian: 9.0
>   Scale_Factor: 0.9996
>   Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.0
>   Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Or WGS84:

> GCS_WGS_1984
>   WKID: 4326 Authority: EPSG
>   Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
>   Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
>   Datum: D_WGS_1984
>   Spheroid: WGS_1984
>   Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
>   Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314245179
>   Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563

Now I realised, that when I load my data into a ETSR89-project and to a Gauss-Krüger-project I have an offset of approximately 200 m between the two points. I used the transformation "DHDN_To_WGS_1984_5x" and "ETRS_1989_To_WGS_1984", respectively. (The "DHDN_To_WGS_1984_4_NTv2" does not give better results.) I found out about this using the calculate geometry function, which unfortunately calculates different WGS84 coordinates depending on the project coordinate system.

How can I make sure my data is on the right spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends where is located the data. Check [Geographic (datum) transformations, parameters and areas of use](http://help.arcgis.com/es/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf) and select which is more accurate to your data. They have small differences in *dy* and *dz* translation.

Conversions are:
[image]

Diferences are:
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Also check [Geographic and Vertical Transformation Tables](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/projections/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf). This document recommends min/max latitude/longitude to select the right transformation between datums. Both sources of information belongs to ESRI:

[image]

Comment: would you have a source of these nice tables?

Comment: Check the link in my answer, oh click [here](http://help.arcgis.com/es/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf)

Comment: is it from ESRI?

Comment: Yes, check the answer now. I update with another reference from ESRI that could help you